# SVN under samba in virtual box very slow

Tags: svn, samba, tortoisesvn

When I use Tortoise SVN on a samba drive inside virtualbox it is exremly slow... is there anyway to config samba to make it any faster? On a local drive it is very fast so it is not the svn server.

Comment: Why are you checking out to a network drive in the first place?

Comment: Because the app only runs in linux but the dev enviroment windows..

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that traffic on the following ports is allowed to the host running Samba.

```
TCP: 139 445
UDP: 135 137 138
```

I inserted the following lines into smb.conf file under [global].

```
read raw = No
write raw = Yes
```

Seemed to speed things up quite a bit. The page linked to below should help. There's a bit on the TCP_NODELAY socket option which is apparently a fantastic option to set.

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/speed.html